# Redirect cnamed domain?

Tags: domain, redirect, cname-record, dns-zone

My client is owning a domain that has this DNS configuration :

- domain.com @ xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- www CNAME domain.com
- static CNAME domain.com

I am managing the server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. This server has WHM installed.

Since it is pointing to my server, is there anyway I can redirect myself static.domain.com (CNAME) to another destination (An Amazon S3 bucket) without asking any change to my client ?

Comment: What is it you want to redirect? If it's HTTP then you could return a `3xx` for the new destination.

Comment: In the end, I would like the domain to act like it is : static CNAME amazon.s3.bucket.url, with the static address still in the address bar when typed

Comment: You could setup a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) for HTTP(s), however this wouldn't be as efficient as having the host name point to the new destination.

Answer (score 3):

If one owns a DNS domain he can set it up as he wants to, making A records point to any possible IP address and CNAME records point to any other DNS name. If he wants to point 'www.example.com' to an IP address you own, there is nothing you can do about it. Similarly, if he sets up a CNAME pointing to your domain, there is nothing you can do about that either.

Thus they must change the CNAME on their side. If you want to more easily change these settings, you could set up a system with two layers of CNAMEs or they might delegate authority of a subdomain to you and then use CNAMEs to point to the subdomain, e.g.

```
www.example.com.     CNAME    www.sub.example.com.
```